# How to run 'resque:work' rake task from rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, jruby, resque

Having followed the rails-cast (http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque?view=comments), I was able to setup my rails application similarly with worker and rake tasks.

However, as specified in the rails-cast, once I start my rails server, I have to issue the following command in a separate terminal window:

```
TERM_CHILD=1 QUEUES=* rake resque:work
```

This gets me up-and-running and I have no issues. However, instead of firing off a rake command on terminal (or writing a startup shell script), I would like to issue this terminal command (TERM_CHILD=1 QUEUES=* rake resque:work) from Rails itself when the application starts up so its available during the duration of the application's uptime on the server.

I am in the process of learning Rails framework so I would greatly appreciate if you can give me some help and let me know how/where to place any code snippet you may provide me with.

Thank you very much in advance.

Here are my environment specs:

- I am using jruby (jruby 1.7.16.1 (1.9.3p392) 2014-10-28 4e93f31 on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_72-b14 +jit [linux-amd64])
- Rails version 4.1.8
- I am developing on LINUX ubuntu 14.04
- I will be deploying this application to Windows 2008 server on a Tomcat server as a WAR package
- I am using PostgreSQL as my database.

Answer (score 1):

That approach would make it difficult to turn off your resque workers. I recommend using a common gem called [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) to handle this. I'll let you look a the documentation, but your Procfile would look something like:

```
web: rails s -p $PORT
resque: TERM_CHILD=1 QUEUES=* rake resque:work
```

And you would be able to start both rails and resque by just running the `foreman` command in console. That will also allow you to exit out of both easily.

**Updated per OP's message:**

```
require 'resque/tasks'
ENV['TERM_CHILD'] = 1
ENV['QUEUES'] = '*'
Thread.new { Rake::Task["resque:work"] }
```

The `Thread.new` is there because it would otherwise cause the rest of the app to never load.

Comment: Thank you however I don't think foreman would fit the bill. 

The problem is, my Windows production server will not have ruby installed on it so using rails/rake/foreman commands would not be possible from the terminal. 

If you can suggest a method for starting the resque workers from within rails itself (I agree, I would like to kill the workers once the rails application has been stopped).

Thank you very much

Comment: Updated for your case.

Comment: Thank you very much -- this is the exact same solution I eventually came up with as well. I placed this code into the initializer and it works like a charm.